# Whats wrong with my code in footer.php

Tags: css, wordpress

I messed up while removing a social media icon on my wordpress site..

my site url elementseventcentre.com

current code in footer.php (whats missing)

```
<footer id="main-footer">
    <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>

    <div id="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <ul id="et-social-icons">
            <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_facebook_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
                <li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_facebook_url', '#' ) ); ?>">
                        <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Facebook', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_twitter_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
                <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_twitter_url', '#' ) ); ?>">
                        <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>





        </div>  <!-- .container -->
    </div>
</footer> <!-- #main-footer -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You ought to tell us what's going wrong and what you expect to happen, before we know how to tell you what's wrong. I did notice that you're missing the closing `</ul>` after the last `<li>` but I don't know if that's what you're complaining about or not.

Comment: Oh..my bad..thanks for replying..yes i did try </ul> but still I need a fooer with the 2 icons - facebook and twitter and I want my image slider to work like before..like a regular slider..rotating with 3 images..thanks again..

Comment: there were also 4 images below the slider with links to land on 4 pages which I cannot see..I am sure I deleted may be just one or two extra lines while deleting code to remove a third social media icon

Comment: your page throws that error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/75/7697875/html/wp-content/themes/Divi/footer.php on line 31`which line is it?

Comment: thanks a lot for replying..I ended up finding orginal code..but this would have totally worked too.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the closing `<ul>` and the close `<?php endif; ?>`.

This is why the footer is to the left and giving the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/75/7697875/html/wp-content/themes/Divi/footer.php on line 31`

That final `if` block should look like:

```
<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_twitter_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_twitter_url', '#' ) ); ?>">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
     </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```